# Getting Speed from GPS or Network Provider

Tags: android, gps, location, android-location

I am creating an application to get speed from GPS and Network provider. I am trying basics first with the following code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 


    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        { 

            //location.getLatitude(); 
            speedText.setText("Current speed:" + location.getSpeed());

        } 

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
        { 

        } 

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {

        } 

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        { 

        } 
    }; 

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

//locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

With Manifext permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

With the above code I get only 0.0 as the value always. Both GPS and Network give the same value. I am not sure where I am going wrong? Can somebody help me fix this part please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why -1 - I thought it is a genuine question...

Answer (score 0):

LocationManager provides you your current Latitude and Longitude based on the GPS satellite. It uses `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` to request updated based on the millis specified. Now after getting your lat and lon you must keep the old position as well as the time then you can do the calculations after getting the next location based on the distance travelled and time to get the speed. What you need now is to make sure you understand how it actually works since you can't get the speed using locationManager as far as I know; only the position. To know more about the LocationManager see the tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)

As for calculating the speed algorithm see it [here](http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/11/14/algorithm-to-calculate-speed-from-two-gps-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-time-difference/)

Comment: The speed algorithm is really bad because it doesn't take into account the gps accuracy. If you want to have a good value you have to use a kalman filter and use the accuracy too as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the speed only on some samples with a real GPS, so you have to check the presence with `hasSpeed()` method. In the emulator you don't receive the speed so you have to use a real phone.

Comment: I am using the real phone. I tried even logging: location.getLatitude() The latitude is not getting changed after it gets the number? As far as I know even a slight move on the phone it changes automatically

Comment: Usually it happens because you have to wait that gps gain the signal, try to move outdoor for a while. Your code is good.

Comment: Try with gps only, set a min time of 1 second, set a min distance of 1 meter and try again. It must work. Is your location listner in a service or activity?

Comment: Then you have to check that your activity is always in foreground for the test

Comment: Yep. I am checking this and it is always in foreground

Comment: If your activity is always in foreground, your gps is on and you are receiving always the same value I think it's a problem with your phone.

Comment: That is what I thought so I tested in another phone it is the same results. And then I tested using some app on playstore. It is working fine on both my phones (Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 5).